# Emscripten AddressSanitizer leak detection

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I'm trying to port a big c++ project using Emscripten, therefore I want to introduce the addressSanitizer. However I don't understand some behavior underneath and hope someone could enlighten me in this quest.

So here is a small set up:

C++ file

```
int leak() {
  const auto testi = new int[10];
  return testi[0]; // LEAK DETECTED
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module)
{
  emscripten::function("leak", &leak);
  emscripten::function("doLeakCheck", &__lsan_do_leak_check);
};
```

Js file

```
const createModule = require('./a.out.js')

async function test() {
    const mod = await createModule();
    mod.leak();
    mod.doLeakCheck();
}

test();
```

Here everything's fine, and the leak is detected. However when I tweak a little bit the `leak` function to

```
int leak() {
  const auto testi = new int[100]; // LEAK not detected
  return 2;
}
```

The only difference here is that I don't export the function. But what happens to the object testi? it is obviously never freed. Is it removed by the compiler ?

Comment: Is `leak` in the 2nd example executed in your tests?  If it never called there is no leak.

Comment: Yes it is called